# DbContext remove parent object Id

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

I've got quite weird problem... Here is what it is... When I'm comparing data from somoe goverment service and checking that last born child in my base is the same like in data from service, after updating parent lastBornChild is loosing connection to parent id and it's updated in db wiht ParentId as NULL.

I know that this code should be written better but I wonder why ef changing my lastBornChild.ParentId to NULL.

```
public class MyService : IMyService
{
    MyService(DataDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }


    private DateTime FindYoungestChild(int parentId)
    {
            var lastChild = _context.Childs.Where(i => i.Parent.Id == parentId).OrderByDescending(d => d.BirthDate).FirstOrDefault();

        if (lastChild == null)
            return DateTime.MinValue;
        else
            return lastChild .BirthDate;
    }

   public Parent UpdateFamilyHistory(Parent parent)
   {

        DateTime lastStatusTransDate = FindYoungestChild(parent.Id);
        var childs= new List<Child>();

        var updateChildList = <some goverment public service response>(d => d.DateTimeCreated > lastStatusTransDate).ToList();

        foreach (var item in updateChildList)
        {
            var newChild = new Child
            {
                Name = item.Name,
                BirthDate = item.BirthDate;
            };

            childs.Add(newChild );
        }

        parent.Childs = childs;

        _context.Update(parent);
        _context.SaveChanges();

        return parent;
    }

}
```

Comment: Why not `parent.Childs.AddRange(childs)`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var childs = new List<Child>();

foreach (var item in updateChildList)
{
    var newChild = new Child
    {
        ParentId = parent.Id,
         Name = item.Name,
        BirthDate = item.BirthDate
    };

childs.Add(newChild);
}
 _context.Childs.AddRange(childs);
_context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Can you format your answer and add correct code syntax markers?

Comment: Sorry, I always trust PO and never check syntax